# Did Sita Ji ask Ram ji to get the golden deer skin after killing it or get it alive?

Tags: ramayana, rama, sita

There are many different versions of this particular incident.

Some says that Sita asked Ram to get the golden deer to make it a pet.

Some says that she asked Ram to get the deer skin so that she with Ram can sit on its skin carpet.

Some says that she initially asked to get the deer as pet but if Ram cannot catch it alive then he can kill it and its skin can be used as carpet.

What did she actually say?

The onces who want to prove that she cannot ask to kill an innocent deer tries to prove the first version while others try to prove the second version.

But what is written in authentic text?

What did she actually ask?

Please give any authentic source of your answer

Comment: Please read the first answer to the question. It includes sita mata's reasons